# How do I use gcc's inline report (-Winline)

Tags: c++, c, gcc, inline

Enabling `-Winline` on my project produces a whole lot of output which I don't really understand. Does anyone know how to use this output to figure out why my particular function wasn't inlined?

Comment: How about giving an example of the output?

Comment: Can you post some code which gives this behavior?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to your question?

Comment: If you think that's bad you should see `-ftree-vectorizer-verbose`

Comment: I've moved on, but I was hoping there was some description of the output somewhere.

Answer (score 3):

Well, according to my gcc man page...

> The compiler uses a variety of
>   heuristics to determine whether or not
>   to inline a function.  For example,
>   the compiler takes into account the
>   size of the function being inlined and
>   the amount of inlining that has
>   already been done in the current
>   function. Therefore, seemingly
>   insignificant changes in the source
>   program can cause the warnings
>   produced by -Winline to appear or
>   disappear.

I don't believe that you can force the compiler to inline your function; it's an implementation detail that could even change when the compiler is updated. Besides, as long as the compiler's choice causes your function to run faster, is there any particular reason that you care whether the function is actually inlined or not?

Of course, if you *really* want to inline your function for some reason, you could probably just use a macro to do so.

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware of the many reasons a function won't be inlined - I guess I was hoping -Winline would give me some useful information about which ones the compiler found.